# Sort reference is not valid?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort some columns horizontally, and keep running into this error. The code seems pretty simple, I'm not sure what I'm missing

I need to move all of the data underneath each column header along with the header, and the amount of headers is subject to change so that's why I used the .End function to select my ranges.

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
    Dim vcHeaders As Range
    Dim vcColumns As Range


Worksheets("Copy").Range("D1").Select
Set vcHeaders = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))

Worksheets("Copy").Range("D:D").Select
Set vcColumns = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Copy").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=vcHeaders
    .SetRange vcColumns
    .Header = xlNo
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

I get the error:

> "Run- time error '1004': The sort reference is not valid. Make sure
>   that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box
>   isn't the same or blank."

EDIT:
I tried specifying vcHeaders and vcColumns as ranges in the Sort function, like the comments suggested, but I got the same error. Those variables are already ranges, and the second one (range) includes the first one (key). I am sorting left to right, so the key is a row, not a columns. I tried specifying it as a row too, and that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: [Put a breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/set-and-clear-a-breakpoint) on the `With` line, [observe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/forms/add-a-watch-expression) which ranges are stored in `vcHeaders` and `vcColumns`, and whether they have blanks in the first row.

Comment: `.SortFields.Add Key:=vcHeaders` is a single-cell range, not a column or multi-cell range... so you want this to read `.SortFields.Add Key:=columns(vcHeaders.column)` ?

Comment: @Cyril The type of `Key` [is `Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add).

Comment: @GSerg good point, and I didn' tput in the appropriate syntax (was originally thinking `key:=2` would do the second column of the range to be sorted, hence just `.column`)... vcheaders is a single cell, when he wants the column... will edi tto use `columns()`